# Many-to-many relationship in Django "ProgrammingError: column shoe_size_run.id does not exist"

Tags: django, database, postgresql

I used the `inspectdb` tool for creating models by introspecting an existing database.

Partial ERD:

[image: ERD]
models.py:

```
class Shoe(models.Model):
    sku = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    style_number = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=6)
    factory_style_number = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    stock_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    season = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    date_created = models.DateField()
    category_code = models.ForeignKey(Category, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='category_code')
    brand_code = models.ForeignKey(Brand, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='brand_code')
    factory_number = models.ForeignKey(Factory, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='factory_number')
    spec_sheet = models.ForeignKey('SpecSheet', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'shoe'

class ShoeSizeRun(models.Model):
    sku = models.ForeignKey(Shoe, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='sku')
    size_run = models.ForeignKey('SizeRun', models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'shoe_size_run'
        unique_together = (('sku', 'size_run'),)

class SizeRun(models.Model):
    size_run_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    run = models.IntegerField()
    width = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    pairs_of_five = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    pairs_of_five_and_half = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    pairs_of_six = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    pairs_of_six_and_half = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    pairs_of_seven = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    pairs_of_seven_and_half = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    pairs_of_eight = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    pairs_of_eight_and_half = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    pairs_of_nine = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    pairs_of_nine_and_half = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    pairs_of_ten = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    pairs_of_ten_and_half = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    pairs_of_eleven = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    pairs_of_eleven_and_half = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    pairs_of_twelve = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'size_run'`
```

While, these are the sql definition for those tables:

```
CREATE TABLE shoe (
  sku                  SERIAL NOT NULL, 
  style_number    varchar(6) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
  factory_style_number varchar(10) UNIQUE, 
  stock_name      varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
  season               varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
  date_created         date NOT NULL, 
  category_code        int4 NOT NULL, 
  brand_code           int4 NOT NULL, 
  factory_number       int4 NOT NULL, 
  spec_sheet_id        int4, 
  PRIMARY KEY (sku));
CREATE TABLE shoe_size_run (
  sku         int4 NOT NULL, 
  size_run_id int4 NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (sku, 
  size_run_id));
CREATE TABLE size_run (
  size_run_id              SERIAL NOT NULL, 
  run                      int4 NOT NULL, 
  width                    varchar(4) NOT NULL, 
  pairs_of_five            int4, 
  pairs_of_five_and_half   int4, 
  pairs_of_six             int4, 
  pairs_of_six_and_half    int4, 
  pairs_of_seven           int4, 
  pairs_of_seven_and_half  int4, 
  pairs_of_eight           int4, 
  pairs_of_eight_and_half  int4, 
  pairs_of_nine            int4, 
  pairs_of_nine_and_half   int4, 
  pairs_of_ten             int4, 
  pairs_of_ten_and_half    int4, 
  pairs_of_eleven          int4, 
  pairs_of_eleven_and_half int4, 
  pairs_of_twelve          int4, 
  PRIMARY KEY (size_run_id));
ALTER TABLE shoe_size_run ADD CONSTRAINT FKshoe_size_544815 FOREIGN KEY (sku) REFERENCES shoe (sku);
ALTER TABLE shoe_size_run ADD CONSTRAINT FKshoe_size_544404 FOREIGN KEY (size_run_id) REFERENCES size_run (size_run_id);
```

Now, I have problems using many-to-many tables in Django. Why this error?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please copy the text content of the stack trace ("switch to copy and paste view") and replace the screenshot with that. Also post the view code that is being called when the error occurs.

Comment: @solarissmoke I just added it, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table `shoe_size_run` has a composite primary key `(sku, 
  size_run_id)`. Unfortunately, Django does not support this yet (see [ticket 373](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/373))

If you want to use the table in Django, you'll have to add a single column primary key to that table. The easiest column name is `id`, since that's what Django expects by default.

Looking at your diagram, you'll need to do the same thing for your `shoe_image` table as well.

Comment: So, I should add a surrogate key named `id` keeping `sku` and `size_run_id` just as foreign keys (but not primary keys). Right?

Comment: As I should edit the existing database, is the only possible solution?

Comment: I'm not aware of any other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The table is `shoe_size_run` and the column is `size_run_id`. So your model field needs to be `size_run_id` rather than `size_run`.